# is Web hook for google review?

Tags: google-api, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

i want my application allows the client (company) to receive, reply of multiple locations of my application's client. The app also allow client to receive and reply to their customers message through other channels like Email and Facebook. So the client don't have to login to multiple application.
I suffer problem that i dont't know when new review appear for my client's location. I wonder if realtime-notification pub/sub of google can handle it ? (https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/notification-setup )

i expect there is webhook for google review that google push message to backend url